Heroku - build of project fullstack (Java and Angular) ended with success, but on app site(run) there is "App Crashed"
I'm quite new to fullstack and Spring Boot, so I ask for patience.
I use a book for fullstack development and I first have tried to read it with understanding and then have run programs from it. Every program with success. Now I try to put the final state of program(fullstack: Java and Angular) to Heroku. The build of program in Heroku is success and there is link to app generated. There, when I open it I always see "App crashed".
In Heroku logs I can find:
 2024-05-14T12:07:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user  
 2024-05-14T12:09:25.641787+00:00 app[api]: Release v78 created by user
 2024-05-14T12:09:25.641787+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 73d058e8 by user  
 2024-05-14T12:09:27.247829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
 crashed to starting 
2024-05-14T12:09:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded 
2024-05-14T12:09:44.374861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting
 process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes
 superheroes/target/classes/com/example/springbootsuperheroes/superheroes/SuperheroesApplication`
 2024-05-14T12:09:45.149791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
 status 1 
2024-05-14T12:09:45.173646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
 from starting to crashed 
2024-05-14T12:09:45.176281+00:00
 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
 2024-05-14T12:09:45.048108+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
 defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
 2024-05-14T12:09:45.051956+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  
2024-05-14T12:09:45.091937+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class
 superheroes.target.classes.com.example.springbootsuperheroes.superheroes.SuperheroesApplication
 2024-05-14T12:10:01.270023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
 command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes
 superheroes/target/classes/com/example/springbootsuperheroes/superheroes/SuperheroesApplication`
 2024-05-14T12:10:02.022777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
 status 1 2024-05-14T12:10:01.923530+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will
 override them. 
2024-05-14T12:10:01.927897+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  
2024-05-14T12:10:01.971485+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class
 superheroes.target.classes.com.example.springbootsuperheroes.superheroes.SuperheroesApplication
 2024-05-14T12:10:02.042973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
 starting to crashed 
2024-05-14T12:10:03.892527+00:00 heroku[router]:
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
 host=anti-hero-fullstack-4cfbfc6dbb64.herokuapp.com
 request_id=187fc38d-b764-4519-86b3-6e485ca2927e fwd="83.23.236.21"
 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2024-05-14T12:10:04.311456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
 host=anti-hero-fullstack-4cfbfc6dbb64.herokuapp.com
 request_id=61fd7730-a803-414e-a35f-b184c1353445 fwd="83.23.236.21"
 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2024-05-14T12:31:11.333043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
 crashed to starting 
2024-05-14T12:31:30.395542+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
 Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes
 superheroes/target/classes/com/example/springbootsuperheroes/superheroes/SuperheroesApplication`
 2024-05-14T12:31:31.120243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
 status 1 
2024-05-14T12:31:31.016516+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will
 override them. 
2024-05-14T12:31:31.020366+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  
2024-05-14T12:31:31.061166+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class
 superheroes.target.classes.com.example.springbootsuperheroes.superheroes.SuperheroesApplication
 2024-05-14T12:31:31.143750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
 starting to crashed


And when I run configuration in IntelliJ, the program starts successfully, but with localhost:8080.
I think there is either something super easy not correct or something difficult.
I am not sure if there should be main class .class file? I tried to generate it but with not success.
I am fighting with this fourth day and I tried with Procfile,with all possible combinations of path I could suppose that can be correct and a lot other things. I originally had my pom.xml file in superheroes project path, but Heroku demands to put it in Root path. Please help me.
The state on 15.05.2024 17:57 is that I changed few things and now there is another behaviour: my app on Heroku is not built with success and there is an error:

Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project superheroes: Could not extract the Node archive: Could not extract archive: '/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/18.16.0/node-18.16.0-linux-x64.tar.gz': Could not get write permissions for '/target/node/tmp/node-v18.16.0-linux-x64/share/doc/node'

I use Windows. think that it is the case for developers of com.github.eirslett but I am not sure. Do you think I can do something about it? I tried a lot and with no success?
Here is my pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.springbootsuperheroes</groupId>
    <artifactId>superheroes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>superheroes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Dto mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OpenAPI 3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>superheroes.src.main.java.example.springbootsuperheroes.superheroes.SuperheroesApplication.java</mainClass>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- START packaging spring and client app in one jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>superheroes/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>../../target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v18.16.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>9.5.1</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install --force</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <!-- check your frontend's dist or build folders -->
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/superheroes/frontend/dist/superheroes"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- END packaging spring and client app in one jar -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


And here is my SuperheroesApplication class with main
package com.example.springbootsuperheroes.superheroes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SuperheroesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SuperheroesApplication.class, args);
    }
}


Here are print screens of my project structure:
Project structure 1
Project structure 2
Project structure 3

Share the link to the book.

The book is not free

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should follow the Heroku documentation for deploying a Spring Boot Application.
My suggestion is to do the following:

Create a new repository
Follow the Heroku documentation tutorial and create a new Spring Boot application and deploy the most simple version of your app using the exact steps listed in this webpage https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku
Once you have your application running Heroku, now you can move your code from the original directory into the working Heroku application repository.

I think if you follow this process, you will get your application set up much faster.
Good luck!

Maybe someone will help me repair my existing project? What @Adam suggested is something I would like to omit

Finally I managed to deploy the app. I saw yesterday a project structure of  heroku fullstack (java + angular)  project on youtube video and it helped a lot
